# Boolean in IF Condition causing Errors in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, boolean

I am developing a webpage with fairly simple JavaScript. My entire JavaScript code is:

```
function showUnlockPopup(isViolated,instId,unlock_done,unlock_total,period,endDate){
        alert(isViolated);
        if(isViolated){
            if(unlock_done < unlock_total){
                showInfoPopup(instId,unlock_done,unlock_total,period);
            } else {
                showNoUnlocksPopup(instId,unlock_done,unlock_total,period,endDate);
            }
        } else {
            showNotViolatedModal();
        }
    }
```

However, irrespective of the value of the 'isViolated' variable, my 'showInfoPopup' function is called.

I have checked the code for the method call too:

```
<button onClick="showUnlockPopup(isViolated)">Unlock</button>
```

The alert shows 'true' or 'false' values correctly, but the logic runs for only 'true' irrespective of the value.

I think I am missing something fairly basic here. I tried a lot, but of no use. Kindly help me with the same.

Comment: What is the type/value passed as `isViolated` variable? If it's a string of "true" and "false", javascript will treat both as true.

Comment: PROTIP: Use `console.log` for debugging, not `alert`.

Comment: Debug your program. Place a breakpoint on the `if (isViolated)` line, and examine the value of `isViolated`.

Comment: try this:  console.log(typeof isViolated)  and see if it's a boolean.

Comment: I assume there's a `}` somewhere you haven't shown.

Comment: Probably the missing ``}`` is causing an error on the if else statement.

Comment: @seahorsepip: In that case, they wouldn't see the alert at all.

Comment: Does the alert show `'true'` or `true`?

Comment: @seahorsepip: A missing `}` would be a syntax error.  The OP says the alert works and `showInfoPopup()` runs.

Comment: HELLO, I had made some changes in the script before posting here due to company policy. But I have pasted the original code in the question, and no bracket is missing here.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: PROTIP: Use a debugger for debugging, not `console.log`.

Comment: Ttry what @StefanYohansson suggested

Comment: It is a boolean value for sure, because it has been declared in the code that way. If I write !isViolated, then the else condition gets exceuted.

Comment: @AdhishThite: The fact that `!isViolated` works doesn't mean `isViolated` is a boolean.  Can you show us where you declare it?

Comment: Yes. The console.log says that it is a STRING. So how do I set this to boolean?

Comment: @AdhishThite: `var isViolated  = true;` is a boolean.  `var isViolated = 'true';` is not.

Comment: @AdhishThite: *"It is a boolean value for sure, because it has been declared in the code that way."* JavaScript variable declarations are typeless. *"If I write !isViolated, then the else condition gets exceuted."* Which doesn't mean it's boolean.

Comment: @AdhishThite simplest way would be just to check if the string is true `isViolated == 'true'` as there is no built in boolean parsing

Comment: @DPac that is exactly what I've suggested below.

Answer (score 0):

it is because `isViolated` is returned as a string. so unless the string is null it will be true if it has some contents. You should change your check to `isViolated` == 'true', make a new variable that is a boolean and assign it depending on `isViolated` or something third.

Comment: Sure, but how do you know that?

Comment: @torazaburo: From the description of the alert, presumably. The OP claims the alert shows true/false.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried it quick on chrome console, `alert(boolvar)` bool and `alert(stringval)` produce the same message (true/false)

Comment: @DPac: Did you mean that comment for torazaburo?